# How to read a list of strings from a vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

The context of my question is this: I am making a text-based game that has a very basic inventory system and reusable input system. Everything is working great, but the inventory system is a bit difficult. The way I am trying to create it is with a vector. The test/example code is this:

```
int main()
{
string item;
vector<string> inv;
cout<<"There is a shotgun and a crowbar. What do you want to take?"<<endl<<"\n>";
getline(cin, item);
cout<<"\nYou decide to take the " << item << endl << "\n";
for(int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++){
cout << inv.at(i) << endl;
}
cin >> item;
}
```

I dont understand what the problem is. There isnt a compiler error. It does confirm what I entered, but nothing happens during the loop, and it automatically goes to my makeshift pause(`the "cin >> item;"`) What I want to happen is to get a line that can include spaces, store it in the inv vector (which will be used as my inventory) and read it off as a list. The for loop, in my mind, should act like this:

```
for(i=0; if i < inventory size (do statement below), then i+1 and restart)
cout << inventory.at(i)
```

i is a growing number which should represent everything in the vector at one time or another, which I could then harness to read the vector strings into a list...

Also, I am very new to C++ and the concept of this dynamic array called a vector. I hesitated to ask this question because of this, and because I couldnt find anything online that answers my question. I have a feeling the answer is staring me in the face...

Comment: In the code you have posted, there are no strings in the inventory which is why the loop does nothing . You don't have any input statements. Can you post some code that actually shows the problem you are having?

Comment: `inv` is still empty when you loop over it... `i = 0; i < inv.size()` works out as `0 < 0` / `false` and the loop's skipped.  You probably want to take the `item` string and break it into individual items to be taken: `std::istringstream iss(item); while (iss >> item) inv.push_back(item);` - though it'd make sense to check that the item was either `"shotgun"` or `"crowbar"` before appending them to `inv`.  Another approach would be `if (item.find("shotgun") != item.end()) inv.push_back("shotgun");` - repeat for crowbar.

Comment: You don't need the pause, and it's doing harm. Instead run your program from a command interpreter. Or if in Visual Studio in Windows, run it via Ctrl+F5. Or place a breakpoint on the last right brace of `main`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `getline` is an input statement.

Comment: wow, i am so sorry. forget about this post. delete if you can. i cant believe i missed that. first time ever posting a question on a forum here, and i completely humiliate myself... btw it now works as expected...

Comment: @Alf oh yeah. I guess he meant to push that line into the vector and then loop.

Comment: yeah, thats what i wanted to do

Comment: *facepalm* times two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vector of tool names is empty, so the loop does nothing.

Replace

```
vector<string> inv;
```

with e.g.

```
vector<string> inv = {"shotgun", "crowbar"};
```

This initialization is supported in C++11 and onward (currently C++14), but was not supported in C++03, where instead you could do e.g.

```
template< class Type, int n >
int n_items( Type (&)[n] ) { return n; }

// ...
static const char * const inv_data[] = {"shotgun", "crowbar"};
vector<string> inv( inv_data, inv_data + n_items( inv_data ) );
```

Note that the C++ standard library unfortunately still as of C++14 does not provide a simple function to uppercase or lowercase a `string`. You will need to create such in order to support uppercase input.

Comment: I see from comments on the question that I probably have misinterpreted what the vector is *for*. That it's not a vector of permissible names but instead a vector of names in use. Well so be it.